# Force network analyst route to follow a certain pattern

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, route

I'm using ArcGis 10.4.1 and network analyst. I'm trying to force,  network analyst route to follow a certain pattern.

[image]

I've tried editing network attributes in network dataset properties and changing values in Global Turn Delay Evaluator, but with no success. 
Instead what network analyst is shown below.

[image].

Can anyone suggest me any solution. I believe that i have to hard code the route behavior.

Comment: The NA toolset is designed calculate the costs between route elements (usually OD pairs) and to find most efficient or least cost solution. I really did not get your purpose and what the second image tells. Your pattern can be anything which makes hard to find a solution. If you want to calculate the cost along the route as given in the first image, you can use Routing analysis and enforce your turn points as stops.

Comment: My purpose is to construct a route that will have very few turns. The second image presents the problem that i m facing, the calculated route has no logic. Try to locate stop no11 (spotted with a red circle) and then tell me if it makes sense what you see.